# Streams reacting conditionally to hot Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to have a component, to asynchronously (and conditionally) react to mouse event streams. Here's a simple scenario:

You hover on `a {@time: 0}`, the component turns to `A {@time:4}`, but by that time, the user has already hovered on `b {@time:2}` then `c {@time:4}`. So the component needs to switch form `A` to `C`.

```
MouseEventStream:  a-b-c-------d-e-f-g--h--------|->
ComponentState:    *---A---*---C---*---F---*---H-|->

* is the idle state
```

I have tried something similar to the following, but I'd need for the filter to buffer some of the events...

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();
.filter(function() {

    return self.isIdle();
})
.map(function(item) {

    return item;
})
.subscribe(function (){
    // do something
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure this is how it needs to be done, I may have found a solution with `buffers` and `pausableBuffered`, manipulating `BehaviorSubject`:

http://jsbin.com/tedolerapo/7/edit?js,output